# Expand tree items on search by making search functionality intact in a tree

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, react-hooks

I am having a tree that is drawn based on an input object. I am having a search bar on the top that basically filters out the items of tree. I want to keep the matched items open when there is a search. The tree should set back to original on clearing of search. Ideally the search should be intact across the tree. When parents are matches, it should  show the tree till that level (children can be collapsed). But when there is children that are matched, all nodes should be opened till the matching node is found

This is what I tried,
https://codesandbox.io/s/modified-tree-final-ovgfv0?file=/src/index.js

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import Tree from "./Tree";
import { data } from "./data";
import "./styles.css";

const TreeList = () => {
  const [search, setSearch] = useState("");

  return (
    <>
      <input
        type="text"
        value={search}
        onChange={(e) => setSearch(e.target.value)}
      />
      <Tree data={data} />
    </>
  );
};

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<TreeList />, rootElement);
```

Comment: We need to see `TreeNode` as well

Comment: And for sibling items of matched elements that *dont* match, what do you want to do, hide them or just keep them there?

Comment: @adsy Just keep them there, collpased

Comment: Right but imagine the situation where theres 2 leaf nodes at the bottom and one matches and one doesn't, what then? As the leaf nodes cant be collapsed.

Comment: @adsy, I guess better way to put it, when parent matches, show the matched parent with its children collapsed. When a leaf node is matches, then show the hierarchy up-till the matched leaf. And yeah, for leaf nodes, there wont be any any expand or collapse icon

Comment: Sorry lots of questions, but these details are key. Are you open to changing the structure slightly? You will need recursion here and you currently have it so the top level is a key/value format but the rest of it is objects containing label/children. This is a slight inconsistency and the solution is easier if its consistent.

Comment: @adsy, what do you think the data structure should be? Yes, go ahead and edit the sandbox with your solution. The format that is in the constants, is the backend one. May be we can convert it to something that you want and go ahead

Comment: Cool, give me some mins

Comment: Ok got it working just need to put the answer together

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So firstly I want to tune the `data` so the format is consistent from top to bottom.

```
export const data = [
  {
    key: "cat1",
    label: "Category 1",
    children: [
      {
        key: "1",
        label: "Applications",
        children: [
          {
            key: "3",
            label: "Browser",
            children: [
              {
                key: "4",
                label: "Mozilla",
                children: []
              },
              {
                key: "5",
                label: "Firefox",
                children: []
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    key: "cat2",
    label: "Category 2",
    children: [
      {
        key: "1",
        label: "Applications",
        children: [
          {
            key: "2",
            label: "OS",
            children: [
              {
                key: "6",
                label: "Windows",
                children: []
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
];
```

This makes it easier to iterate over recursively.

Now we will change index JS so that we return a modified version of the tree that has properties added to each node, `matched` and `hasMatchedChildren`. We additionally set the `key` of the root `<TreeList>` to refresh the whole tree (including the open/collapsed state a user might have changed) every time you type.

```
import React, { useMemo, useState } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import Tree from "./Tree";
import { data } from "./data";
import "./styles.css";

function searchTree(tree, query) {
  function traverse(node, query) {
    const matchedChildren = node.children.map((child) =>
      traverse(child, query)
    );
    const isMatch = node.label.toLowerCase().includes(query.toLowerCase());
    const hasMatchedChildren = matchedChildren.some(
      (child) => child.matched || child.hasMatchedChildren
    );

    return {
      ...node,
      children: matchedChildren,
      matched: isMatch,
      hasMatchedChildren: hasMatchedChildren
    };
  }

  return tree.map((root) => traverse(root, query));
}
const TreeList = () => {
  const [search, setSearch] = useState("");

  const tree = useMemo(() => searchTree(data, search), [search]);

  return (
    <>
      <input
        type="text"
        value={search}
        onChange={(e) => setSearch(e.target.value)}
      />
      <Tree
        key={search}
        data={tree}
        defaultCollapse={search === "" ? false : null}
      />
    </>
  );
};

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<TreeList />, rootElement);
```

`Tree.js` is now changed to reflect the slightly different format:

```
import React from "react";
import TreeNode from "./TreeNode";

const Tree = ({ data = [], defaultCollapse }) => {
  return (
    <div className="d-tree">
      <ul className="d-flex d-tree-container flex-column">
        {data.map((node) => (
          <TreeNode
            key={node.key}
            node={node}
            defaultCollapse={defaultCollapse}
          />
        ))}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Tree;
```

Finally, and crucially, `TreeNode` is changed so the collapse state is defaulted to if there is a matched child or not.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome";

const TreeNode = ({
  node,
  parentWasDirectMatch = false,
  defaultCollapse,
  level = 1
}) => {
  const [childVisible, setChildVisiblity] = useState(
    defaultCollapse !== null ? defaultCollapse : node.hasMatchedChildren
  );

  const hasChild = node.children && node.children.length > 0;
  const nodeStyle = level === 1 ? { fontWeight: "bold", color: "red" } : {};

  if (
    ((!hasChild && !node.matched) ||
      (!node.matched && !node.hasMatchedChildren)) &&
    !parentWasDirectMatch
  ) {
    return null;
  }

  return (
    <li className="d-tree-node border-0">
      <div className="d-flex" onClick={(e) => setChildVisiblity((v) => !v)}>
        {hasChild && (
          <div
            className={`d-inline d-tree-toggler ${
              childVisible ? "active" : ""
            }`}
          >
            <FontAwesomeIcon icon="caret-right" />
          </div>
        )}
        <div className="col d-tree-head" style={nodeStyle}>
          {node.label}
        </div>
      </div>

      {hasChild && childVisible && (
        <div className="d-tree-content">
          <ul className="d-flex d-tree-container flex-column">
            {node.children.map((item) => (
              <TreeNode
                key={item.key}
                node={item}
                level={level + 1}
                parentWasDirectMatch={node.matched || parentWasDirectMatch}
                defaultCollapse={defaultCollapse}
              />
            ))}
          </ul>
        </div>
      )}
    </li>
  );
};

export default TreeNode;
```

Working codesandbox is [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/modified-tree-final-forked-op1x0k).

Comment: Thanks so much. Just to be clear two cases. 1) By default the tree state should be collapsed.2) when oen of the leaf node is matching, only that has to be shown along with this path.  For Ex: when I search 'Firefox' even 'Mozilla 'is shown and also the category 2 is also shown when there isnt any match in the second category

Comment: Ok i misunderstood. This should be easy to edit though. This is what I meant about what to do with the leaf nodes in my original comment. The category 2 thing is  a bug though. Can fix but distracted atm, will come back to it.

Comment: Give me like an hour or two, I'm just in a cs game lmao

Comment: Ok, try the latest version,